# Can you have a fullwidth table in tufte_handout pdfs?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, tufte

I'm using the tufte::tufte_handout class in RMarkdown/Rstduio. Is there a way to get a full-width table, as you can a full width image/plot?

EDIT: Just to be clear, I know how make figures full width with the relevant chunk options. Here I want to have the same effect on a *table*

I'm wondering also whether this is more of a latex question than rmarkdown, so have added that tag.

EDIT2: As a minimal non-working example see:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: tufte::tufte_handout
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(pander)
library(tidyverse)
```


```{r, fig.fullwidth = TRUE}
cars %>% t %>% head(20) %>% pander
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can think of to get a full-width table working in Tufte Handouts is to use the (*awesome*) `kableExtra` package. This package gives you a lot more formatting and editing options and I would recommend looking into these guides here: [Guide 1](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf) & [Guide 2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html).

This is the code I got it working with:

````
---
title: "Tufte Handout"
output:
  tufte::tufte_handout:
    includes:
      in_header: testheader.tex
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tufte)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy = FALSE, cache.extra = packageVersion('tufte'), 
kable.force.latex = TRUE)
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
```

## Full width table

This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a 
test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.

```{r, resize.width=100, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(magrittr)
library(kableExtra)
knitr::kable(mtcars[1:6, 1:6], format = "latex", booktabs=T, 
table.envir='table*') %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("hold_position"), full_width=T)
```
````

Tex header (testheader.tex) for kableExtra:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
```

A couple of things are important to get it working which is why I am highlighting it here. Namely: `kable.force.latex = TRUE` and `table.envir='table*'`. Obviously you might not need everything that you find in the code and tex header so please feel free to adjust accordingly.

Output looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this just applies to figures, not tables. I think I perhaps wasn't clear enough in my original question so have edited now.

Comment: Apologies, I should have read your question a bit more thoroughly too. I will amend my answer.